# Sum over prime and sum over prime ideals

Tags: number-theory, analytic-number-theory, maximal-and-prime-ideals

The Chebyshev equivalent is well-known:
$$\sum_{p < x} \frac{\log p}{p} \sim \log x.$$

I am interested in the number field setting. How can I deduce (for instance I tried to encapsulated ideals of constant norm) a similar equivalent in for prime ideals, i.e. is there a constant $C$ such that
$$\sum_{n(\mathfrak{p}) < x} \frac{\log N\mathfrak{p}}{N\mathfrak{p}} \sim C \log x,$$

where the sum runs over prime ideals and $n$ is the norm on the number field? The constant should probably be a residue of the Dedekind zeta function on the field. Is it straightforward? Or do you have any reference?